# MediaProjection - find a match in the screenshot

Tags: java, android, android-mediaprojection, mediaprojection

I am able to make a screenshot with MediaProjection in android Java

what is the best way to find a image (lets say icon) in the screenshot, and get the coordinates of it , or click on it ?

Comment: Take a look at `AccessibilityService`, that provides all the views that are on screen. Scanning for an icon is prone to errors, especially with limited knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @Micheal, i will have a look at Accessibility.I used icon just as example, i did a previous project to automate a game in android for which i used Ankulua. i want to try and do the same with Java, but its proven a bit more difficult than anticipated